# How to check a file is already opened in CreateFile function in Windows

Tags: c, file, winapi, createfile

I have to open a handle for a file, before opening the file I need to check whether the file is already opened by another entity. I read CREATE_NEW parameter fails to open the file if already exist. I am opening the file using the api and parameters `CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);`

Another entity already opened the file, but when I try to open the same file by calling the above api it returns a proper handle and even the getLastError() returns SUCCESS. But expectation is FAILURE should be returned.

Comment: Why do you care? Open the file with the desired access and share mode, and implement appropriate error handling in case the file cannot be opened. This also removes the potential [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race condition.

Comment: Opening the file with `CREATE_NEW` can tell you if the file itself exists at all (`CreateFile()` will fail with an `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` error), but not whether anyone else has the file open. The combination of `dwDesiredAccess` and `dwShareMode` determine that, not the `dwCreationDisposition`. By setting `dwShareMode` to 0, you should be getting an `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` error if the file is already open.

Comment: If you are only interested in checking for a open file, but don't actually want to open the file yourself, an alternative is to try using the [`IFileIsInUse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775874.aspx) interface instead of `CreateFile()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It doesn't sound like [IFileIsInUse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775874.aspx) can be used universally. Applications need to (manually) insert a `IFileIsInUse` object into the ROT. While convenient, `IFileIsInUse` requires the cooperation of other applications to work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is already correct. You are passing `0` as the share mode which opens the file with exclusive access. No other party can open the file while that handle lives.

The documentation says this about exclusive share mode:

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.

The logical conclusion from all of this is that you are mistaken in your belief that another party has the file open when you call `CreateFile`. If what you report in the question is correct, that cannot be true.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to open your file in exclusive mode. If you are able to do that then it means it is not being used by another process else it is being used.

```
CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

The dwShareMode which when set to 0 will mean that it is exclusive access. [MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If this parameter is zero and CreateFile succeeds, the file or device
>   cannot be shared and cannot be opened again until the handle to the
>   file or device is closed.

Comment: Yes, even I tried to open with the Exclusing mode. but I could not find any parameters to open a file in Exclusive mode. Could you please share a code snippet!!!

Comment: `dwShareMode` set to zero is exclusive access.